# regex match with in { }

Tags: php, regex

I'm having a lot of issues with matching all items that are in brackets.

Here is some code, what I need the matches to do is output something like

```
Array ( [0] => username [1] => id )
```

some code to give you an idea

```
$ur = '/account/{username}/{id}';
if(preg_match('', $str, $matches)){
   print_r($matches);
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Are you trying to retrieve the username and id from that string and store those values in an array?

Comment: I'm guessing it should be more like /account/vince88/1234

Comment: I think i need something like what  Scuzzy said like a got a value $match = '/account/{username}/{id}' and $ur = '/account/{username}/{id}'  and i need to match ur to match .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ur = '/account/{username}/{id}';
preg_match_all('/\{([a-z]+)\}/',$ur,$m);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($m[1]);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "username"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "id"
}
```